# Java - Make inner classes be able to modify outer class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class OuterClass {
    String string = "helloworld";

    public class InnerClass {

        public void main(String[] args) {
            string = "lol";
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    public void changeString() {
        InnerClass c = new InnerClass();
        c.changeString();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
lol
helloworld
```

Is there a way for the inner class to be able to modify the variables of the outer class?
Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: you cannot change non-static variable in class, you can change variable in object instance

Comment: Also you called `c.changeString()` which non-statically is `InnerClass.changeString()`, which wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the variable *string* is **static** you can now access it from any class inside the class the variable is defined in i.e.***InnerClass*** and therefore you can change the variable's value from ***InnerClass*** and also ***OuterClass***. So the code will be:

```
public class OuterClass {
    public static String string = "helloworld";

    public class InnerClass {
        string = "lol";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does string = "lol" not give compilation issue? Or Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 2):

Pass a reference to the outer class to the inner class in the constructor

```
public class InnerClass {

    private OuterClass parent;

    public InnerClass(OuterClass parent)
    {
       this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void changeString() 
    {
        parent.string = "lol";
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

then inside of the class would instantiate using `new InnerClass(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a change in the code where the inner class accesses outer class' object and modifies it.

```
public class OuterClass
{
    String string = "helloworld";

    public class InnerClass
    {
        public void changeString()
        {
            string = "lol";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();
        System.out.println(outerClass.string);
        outerClass.new InnerClass().changeString();
        System.out.println(outerClass.string);
    }
}
```

It's output is:

```
helloworld
lol
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass an instance of the outer class to the inner class' constructor, then assign it to a member variable, then you can reference that member variable

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't compile, but you could fix that with something like

```
static String string = "helloworld";

static class InnerClass {
    public void changeString() {
        string = "lol";
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InnerClass c = new InnerClass();
    c.changeString();
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
lol
lol
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment below, and using Java 8

```
String string = "helloworld";
public class InnerClass {
    public void changeString() {
        string = "lol";
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OuterClass m = new OuterClass();
    InnerClass c = m.new InnerClass();
    c.changeString();
    System.out.println(m.string);
}
```

Comment: But this is something completely different because it doesn't modify an instance variable anymore.